# How to calculate Pairwise Correlation Difference?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I was trying to implement the pairwise correlation difference (PCD) found in the following paper.

https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-020-00977-1

PCD measures the difference in terms of Frobenius norm of the Pearson correlation matrices computed from real and synthetic datasets. The smaller the PCD, the closer the synthetic data is to the real data in terms of linear correlations across the variables. PCD is defined as

$$\text{PCD}(X_R, X_S) = ||\text{Corr}(X_R) - \text{Corr}(X_S)||_F$$

where,
$$X_R = \text{Real Data Matrix}$$
$$X_S = \text{Synthetic Data Matrix}$$
$$F = \text{Frobenius norm}$$
$$\text{Corr} = \text{Pearson Correlation}$$

Here,
$X_R$ and $X_S$ both are of dimension $m \times n$ where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and each row is a binary vector. For example,

```
X_R = [
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

```
X_S = [
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
]
```

Now, could you please tell me how do I implement the above formula with `scipy.stats.pearsonr` method?

Comment: You first have to create the correlation matrices (e.g. using something like [`numpy.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)), after which you can use [`numpy.lingalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to calculate the Frobenius norm of the difference between the two correlation matrices.